# Prometheus service is running, but it does not work in browser on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have followed the following tutorial to install and configure Prometheus on EC2 instance

https://codewizardly.com/prometheus-on-aws-ec2-part1/

I can access it from ssh and check it is status and it is working, but when try to open it from browser it does not open, although I have a security group with the required ports open (9090, 9100, 9093)

This is the output of : `sudo systemctl status prometheus`

```
Nov 22 16:20:03 ip-172-31-22-19 prometheus[462]: level=info ts=2022-11-22T16:20>
Nov 22 16:20:03 ip-172-31-22-19 prometheus[462]: level=info ts=2022-11-22T16:20>
Nov 22 16:20:03 ip-172-31-22-19 prometheus[462]: level=info ts=2022-11-22T16:20>
Nov 22 16:20:03 ip-172-31-22-19 prometheus[462]: level=info ts=2022-11-22T16:20>
Nov 22 16:20:03 ip-172-31-22-19 prometheus[462]: level=info ts=2022-11-22T16:20>
Nov 22 16:20:03 ip-172-31-22-19 prometheus[462]: level=info ts=2022-11-22T16:20>
Nov 22 16:20:03 ip-172-31-22-19 prometheus[462]: level=info ts=2022-11-22T16:20>
Nov 22 16:20:08 ip-172-31-22-19 prometheus[462]: level=info ts=2022-11-22T16:20>
Nov 22 16:20:08 ip-172-31-22-19 prometheus[462]: level=info ts=2022-11-22T16:20>
Nov 22 16:20:08 ip-172-31-22-19 prometheus[462]: level=info ts=2022-11-22T16:20>
```